# What are the consequences of failing to close a query or persistence manager?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I see from every example for the appengine datastore that it is important to surround query executions, etc with try{}finally{} blocks to ensure that queries are always closed.

What happens if a query or persistence manager isn't closed, but goes out of scope?  Could an entity ever be made permanently inaccessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Closing a PersistenceManager](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/PersistenceManager.html#close%28%29)
>   might release it to the pool of
>   available PersistenceManagers, or
>   might be garbage collected, at the
>   option of the JDO implementation.

My interpretation of that is that if you let a PersistanceManager go out of scope without closing it then it *will* be garbage collected and will *not* be released to the pool of available PersistenceManagers, which *may* cause additional overhead when calling PersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager() if there are no more available PersistenceManagers.